Size of Operator and trying it to print array
Consider this C program
#include <stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(arr))/sizeof(arr[0])
int arr[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};
int main() {
 int d;
 printf("%zu\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
 for (d = -1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++) {
  printf("%d ", arr[d + 1]);
 }
 return 0;
}

compilers are giving output as 7
according to my dry run and reasoning output should be
7
23 34 12 17 204 99 16
Now in order to see what is going wrong I applied some Variation
consider this code
#include <stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(arr))/sizeof(arr[0])
int arr[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};
int main() {
 int d;
 printf("%zu\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
 for (d = -1; d <=(int) ((TOTAL_ELEMENTS) - 2); d++) {
  printf("%d ", arr[d + 1]);
 }
 return 0;
}

Notice that the only change I done is introducing type casting with int, and now it's giving expected results.
Now as much as I know when we compare in C program it can do conversion to bigger data-type right, so suppose TOTAL_ELEMENT even has bigger type like long then d should be converted to long and program should run fine but that is not happening. What points I am missing here?

Please revise to clarify question you want answered.

@AllanWind thank you very much this clarifies my doubt here we are comparing unsigned with signed that does mean signed will be converted to huge number according to unsigned and condition will be false right?
